# Invalid object name in a query with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem:

I have 3 tables:
[image]
If you want to create a document, there are two options:

1. You can create a Document from scratch.

   - The program will create a record in the Config table with default configuration.
   - In this case 1 Config record belongs to exactly 1 Document record
2. You can create a Document from a DocumentTemplate

   - DocumentTemplate allows you to pre-define Document configurations where you can base Documents on.
   - The program will link the new record in the Document table to the same configuration record as the DocumentTemplate configuration record.
   - 1 Config record belongs to exactly 1 DocumentTemplate record and belongs to 0..* Document records

If you have never created a template, the table 'DocumentTemplate' will not exist in the database.

Now I want to select the following columns:

1. Config.config_data
2. Document.document_name **OR** DocumentTemplate.template_name

   - **If** config is created by a template I want DocumentTemplate.template_name
   - **Else** I want Document.document_name

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT 
-- //Name must be name of Document or name of DocumentTemplate 
CASE 
    WHEN [c].[config_from_template] = 0 
    THEN -- //Get Document name
        (SELECT [d].[document_name]
        FROM [Document] [d]
        WHERE [d].[document_config_id] = [c].[config_id])
    WHEN [c].[config_from_template] = 1 
    AND OBJECT_ID ('[DocumentTemplate]','U') IS NOT NULL
    THEN -- //Get template name
        (SELECT [t].[template_name]
        FROM [DocumentTemplate] [t]
        WHERE [t].[template_config_id] = [c].[config_id])
END as 'Name',
configNode.value('@Key', 'nvarchar(128)') as 'ConfigKey', -- //Key from xml @Key    
configNode.value('@Value', 'nvarchar(128)') as 'ConfigValue' -- //Value from xml @Value 
FROM [Config] [c]
-- //Create one record for each config option
CROSS APPLY [Config].[config_data].nodes('//ConfigOptions') as ConfigNodes(configNode)
```

This query will throw a syntax error if DocumentTemplate does not exist.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'DocumentTemplate'.

**How can I rewrite this query to meet my requirements?**

thanks in advance

Comment: "If you have never created a template, the table `DocumentTable` will not exist in the database." - this is a HIGHLY unusual design. An application database with no data of a particular kind should have an *empty* table, not *no table at all* !

Comment: (+1 @Aakashm) I am sorry I mean `DocumentTemplate` in place of `DocumentTable`. But I agree. I am using a framework so I have to accept this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because the engine always checks the validity of your code, regardless whether it will be executed or not.

Maybe you can work around this check be executing the subquery like this:

```
EXEC ('SELECT [t].[template_name]
   FROM [DocumentTemplate] [t]
   WHERE [t].[template_config_id] = ' + CAST([c].[config_id] AS VARCHAR(10)')
```

I did not check whether this works and may even have a typo in it. But it should serve as a point to start from...